# MySQL SUM() always returns a 0 value

Tags: mysql, sum

I have amounts stored as a varchar in my table.

When attempting to sum them it always returns 0.00.

Below is an example using only one record from the db.

```
SELECT col1, SUM(CAST(col2 AS DECIMAL(20,2))) derived1
                    FROM table
                    WHERE col3 = 'FIT' 
                    AND col1 = '6211195'
                    GROUP BY col1
```

This returns one row with a 0 value.
By removing the SUM and CAST from the query, I can see that it is pulling the value as it should, but I can not sum or cast it, adding either of those breaks it and returns 0 again.
I have also tried converting the field to a decimal type and it just zeros all the values.

EDIT:

Ughh, I just ran a REGEX query to detect anything that isnt an alphanumeric value or a decimal point. It appears that there are non ascii characters in the field that I cant see, messing with the type casting. Will continue to update as I learn more.

Comment: what is the datatype of col2AS ?

Comment: Sorry, COL2 is a VARCHAR

Comment: Ughh, I just ran a REGEX query to detect anything that isnt an alphanumeric value or a decimal point. It appears that there are non ascii characters in the field that I cant see, messing with the type casting. Will continue to update as I learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Show some sample values of `col2`.  A string that really is a number is treated as a number.  Hence `'1'` will become `1`.

However, if the string does not start with a digit,  `'-'`, or `'+'` (after leading spaces), then it will be `0` (in most cases).  So `'A1'` will be `0`.  And so on.  As will `'$100'`.

The lesson is:  If a column contains numbers, store them as numbers.  Really simple.